# Get one result from 2 observables with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am new at RxJava and I have some pain to execute my first 'difficult' query.

I have two Observables generated from Retrofit, one that 'ping' a new api, the other the old one. The first one will query 'http://myurl.com/newapi/ping', the second one 'http://myurl.com/oldapi/ping'. Result from this request doesn't matter, I just want to know if the server is using the new or old api.

So I would like to call both observables at the same time, and finally have a boolean at the end to know if I'm using old or new api.

I tried something like that

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(obsOldApi,obsNewApi)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(), true)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {
                }
            });
```

But onError will be called once (I would like it to be called only if both request failed) and when onNext is called, I don't know from which request it came (old or new api ?).

Thank you for you help

Comment: You could use `onErrorResume`, but that would mean calling one api only if the other fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, let say that you'll received `"NEW"` or `"OLD"` regarding which api is available.

The difficulty of your operation is to manage errors : RxJava deals errors as terminal state. So you'll have to ignore this error, using `.onErrorResumeNext()` for example.

```
   Observable<String> theOld = oldApi.map(r -> "OLD")
                                     // ignore errors
                                     .onErrorResumeNext(Obervable.empty());

   Observable<String> theNew = newApi.map(r -> "NEW")
                                     .onErrorResumeNext(Obervable.empty());


   Observable.merge(theOld, theNew)
             .first() // if both api are in errors
             .subscribe(api -> System.out.println("Available API : "+api));
```

I added the operator `first` : it will take only the first result (`"OLD"` or `"NEW"`) but trigger an error if the previous `Observable` is empty, which is the case if both API are unavaible.